# How Do I Perform A Text Animation in Python?

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I am creating a GUI application in python that is a "Lingo" word game. On my home screen in my GUI, I am trying to have characters appear on the screen every 1 second. However, I am new to this type of python programming and am unsure on how to do it. I have the following characters I want to appear one at a time that make up the following words.

"leads"
"large"
"lists"
"loins"
"lingo"

At the moment these characters appear in different x and y locations on the GUI screen. For example, with the word leads, I want "l" to appear after 1 second, then "e", and so on. I intend for these characters to appear in their current positions after 1 second, sequentially. I have tried to use time.sleep() and the after() function, but I can't get these to work. Any suggestions on how I can perform this animation? Basically, I am trying to implement the user playing the game as a background animation when the GUI game first runs.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import numpy as np
import time

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = '500', width = '500')
canvas.pack()

#Create Title Lingo Balls
canvas.create_oval(30,10,100,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)
canvas.create_oval(120,10,190,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)
canvas.create_oval(210,10,280,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)
canvas.create_oval(300,10,370,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)
canvas.create_oval(390,10,460,80, outline = "medium blue", fill = "medium blue", width = 2)

#Print Letters Inside of Lingo Ball Circles
letterfont = tkFont.Font(size = 30)
l = canvas.create_text((65, 46), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
i = canvas.create_text((155, 46), text= "I", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
n = canvas.create_text((245, 46), text= "N", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
g = canvas.create_text((335, 46), text= "G", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
o = canvas.create_text((425, 46), text= "O", font = letterfont, fill = "white")

#Create Homepage Game Board
canvas.create_rectangle(210,220,280,290, outline = "blue", fill = "blue", width = 200)
canvas.create_line(164,120,164,390, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(218,120,218,390, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(272,120,272,390, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(326,120,326,390, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(110,174,380,174, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(110,228,380,228, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(110,282,380,282, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(110,336,380,336, fill = "white")

canvas.create_rectangle(110,120,164,174, outline = "white", fill = "red") #create red squares for correctly guessed letters
canvas.create_rectangle(110,174,164,228, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(110,228,164,282, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(110,282,164,336, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(110,336,164,390, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(272,174,326,228, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(164,228,218,282, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(164,336,218,390, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(218,336,272,390, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(272,336,326,390, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(326,336,380,390, outline = "white", fill = "red")
canvas.create_rectangle(164,282,218,336, outline = "white", fill = "yellow") #create yellow squares for guessed letters that are in word, but out of place
canvas.create_rectangle(218,282,272,336, outline = "white", fill = "yellow")
canvas.create_rectangle(272,282,326,336, outline = "white", fill = "yellow")


l = canvas.create_text((137, 147), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
e = canvas.create_text((191, 147), text= "E", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
a = canvas.create_text((245, 147), text= "A", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
d = canvas.create_text((299, 147), text= "D", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
s = canvas.create_text((353, 147), text= "S", font = letterfont, fill = "white")


l = canvas.create_text((137, 201), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
a = canvas.create_text((191, 201), text= "A", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
r = canvas.create_text((245, 201), text= "R", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
g = canvas.create_text((299, 201), text= "G", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
e = canvas.create_text((353, 201), text= "E", font = letterfont, fill = "white")

l = canvas.create_text((137, 255), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
i = canvas.create_text((191, 255), text= "I", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
s = canvas.create_text((245, 255), text= "S", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
t = canvas.create_text((299, 255), text= "T", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
s = canvas.create_text((353, 255), text= "S", font = letterfont, fill = "white")

l = canvas.create_text((137, 309), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
o = canvas.create_text((191, 309), text= "O", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
i = canvas.create_text((245, 309), text= "I", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
n = canvas.create_text((299, 309), text= "N", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
s = canvas.create_text((353, 309), text= "S", font = letterfont, fill = "white")

l = canvas.create_text((137, 363), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
i = canvas.create_text((191, 363), text= "I", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
n = canvas.create_text((245, 363), text= "N", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
g = canvas.create_text((299, 363), text= "G", font = letterfont, fill = "white")
o = canvas.create_text((353, 363), text= "O", font = letterfont, fill = "white")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic concept of animation in tkinter is to start by writing a function that can do one frame of the animation, and then having another function call it and then schedules itself to be called again in the future.

So, let's start with a function named `draw` which draws a single letter in a box at a given coordinate:

```
def draw(canvas, char, x, y, color):
    """Draw one character in a box at the given coordinate"""

    text_id = canvas.create_text(x, y, text=char, anchor="nw", font=letterfont)
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(text_id)
    box_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x0-1, y0-1, x1+1, y1+1, fill=color, outline="black")
    canvas.lift(text_id, box_id)
```

Next, write a function that calls this function via `after`. In this case it pulls one character off of the string at a time, and continues to do so every second until the string has been fully displayed.

```
def animate(canvas, string, x, y, color):
    """Draw each character in the string at one second intervals. """
    draw(canvas, string[0], x, y, color)
    if len(string) > 1:
        string = string[1:]
        canvas.after(1000, animate, canvas, string, x+width, y, color)
```

I do not recommend you use this code exactly as is. It computes the coordinate of each letter even though you've pre-computed the coordinates, plus it would be better to implement this as a class or part of a class.

Regardless, the technique remains the same and hinges on the `animate` function scheduling itself with `after`, and then calling some other function to perform one frame of animation.

---

Here is the above code in a complete program:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
letterfont = tkFont.Font(size = 30)
width = letterfont.measure("0")

def draw(canvas, char, x, y, color):
    """Draw one character in a box at the given coordinate"""

    text_id = canvas.create_text(x, y, text=char, anchor="nw", font=letterfont)
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(text_id)
    box_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x0-1, y0-1, x1+1, y1+1, fill=color, outline="black")
    canvas.lift(text_id, box_id)

def animate(canvas, string, x, y, color):
    """Draw each character in the string at one second intervals. """
    draw(canvas, string[0], x, y, color)
    if len(string) > 1:
        string = string[1:]
        canvas.after(1000, animate, canvas, string, x+width, y, color)

animate(canvas, "Leads", 2, 2, "bisque")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the characters one at a time, you can set the text object to hidden at the start then use a timer to show each letter in sequence.

```
lstltr = [  # store all letter object ids in list
canvas.create_text((137, 147), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),
canvas.create_text((191, 147), text= "E", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),
canvas.create_text((245, 147), text= "A", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),
canvas.create_text((299, 147), text= "D", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),
canvas.create_text((353, 147), text= "S", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),

............

canvas.create_text((137, 363), text= "L", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),
canvas.create_text((191, 363), text= "I", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),
canvas.create_text((245, 363), text= "N", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),
canvas.create_text((299, 363), text= "G", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN),
canvas.create_text((353, 363), text= "O", font = letterfont, fill = "white", state= tk.HIDDEN)
]

def countdown(idx):
    # change text in label        
    if idx < len(lstltr):
        canvas.itemconfigure(lstltr[idx], state=tk.NORMAL) # show letter object
        root.after(100, countdown, idx+1)  # 1/10 second

countdown(0)  # start timer

root.mainloop()
```